# Configure NGinx to distribute laravel in a subfolder

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, subdirectory

I try to configure Nginx to distribute my laravel api on a subfolder of my domain

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name stackoverflow.com;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

    charset utf-8;

    location /dev {

        alias /home/debian/www/stackoverflow/api/dev/public;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /dev/index.php?$query_string;

        location = /dev/favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location = /dev/robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

        error_page 404 /dev/index.php;
        error_log /home/debian/logs/nginx/error_log;
        access_log /home/debian/logs/nginx/access_log;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I tried different configuration, with /dev on try_files, without /dev, but always same result "File not found" and in error log :

> *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 109.221.246.178, server: xxx, request: "GET /dev/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock:", host: "xxx"

or

> *1 open() "/home/debian/www/xxx/api/dev/public/login" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xxx, server: xxx, request: "GET /dev/login HTTP/1.1", host: "xxx"

My poor knowledge on Nginx stop there. I know its about a file path issue, but can't understand where...
The configuration works perfectly when I try to set up on location / { }

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 2):

This is my based conf when i put laravel app in domain subfolder, you can try to add your custom settings on it.

My laravel app root is in "subsite" folder, so you may change "subsite" to "dev" and test it.

```
location /subsite {
    alias /var/www/project/subsite/public/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @subsite;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
    }
}
    
location @subsite {
    rewrite /subsite/(.*)$ /subsite/index.php?/$1 last;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, it is very upfull and I did a step forward !
Now my Laravel respond, and everything is working, except it looks like Laravel receive only "GET method".
I use Postman to try my API, and I when I send my "POST" request, it said that "GET" method is not allowed for that route...

I will search, any ideas ?

Comment: Looks like it might be laravel route problem or request method not set to right, suggest to open a new question and post your route code on it. I can't debug without any details :(

Comment: The fact is it perfectly works on my local server or when I configure Laravel on root directory. I debuged "$request_method" and it always return "GET", except when I access the root route "/" !
I'm so confuse...

Comment: You should confirm that nginx received your request POST or GET first, you can check logs where probably in /var/log/nginx/access.log. If nginx received POST that means it's laravel app problem.

Comment: And make sure your app base url set to right, for example nginx conf server_name set to "stackoverflow.com/dev" and env APP_URL to "stackoverflow.com/dev" too. Those things is what you need to notice when you set app root in subfolder.

Comment: Then check your router with `php artisan route:list` to see if route is right. If can't find issue, than you should post how you send request and router detail on anther quest.

Comment: - Nginx receive "POST" method inside access log, why $request_method has not the same value ?
- Laravel env APP_URL and Nginx server_name have both "/dev" at the end
- With artisan command I can see that all my routes have "POST" on the route I'm testing.
When I try to access a "GET" route it perfectly works...
Thats non sense !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251620/discussion-between-dimitri-and-charlie).

Comment: did you find a solution for this? In my case only HEAD request are allowed.