# Nginx configuration for multiple laravel applications in subdirectory

Tags: laravel, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have multiple Laravel applications hosted on an Ubuntu server. However, there is only a single domain to access all these apps under different paths. For example, consider following the directory structure & domain.

Domain: my-domain.com

See the below directory structure in which `myapps` is the web server root directory:

```
- myapps
   - apps
       - app_1
       - app_2
       - app_3
   - apis
       - api_1
       - api_2
       - api_3
```

The above apps must be accessible via

`my-domain.com\apps\app_1`

`my-domain.com\apps\app_2`

`my-domain.com\apps\app_3`

`my-domain.com\apis\api_1`

and so on.

I was trying to modify the nginx configuration to get this working, but I am getting

> File not found.

error when any of the apps is accessed. I am using the following nginx configuration

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl http2;
    listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name
        my-domain.com
      ;

    root   /srv/users/usr1/apps/myapps/apps;

    location /apps/app_1 {
        alias /srv/users/usr1/apps/myapps/apps/app_1/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        location ~ ^/app_1\.php$ {
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        }
    }

    proxy_set_header    Host              $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-SSL   on;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

As I checked the logs for nginx, apache and PHP, I can see the following error in the apache error logs

> [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 30519:tid 139697879729920] [client xx.xxx.xx.xxx:0] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown'

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: can't you make multiple nginx configs? Per site 1 config, per api 1 config. The host im the nginx config is one of those subdomains

Comment: @UnderDog I am using multiple configs per app. To make it easy I have only posted one of them in the question.

Comment: take a really close look at for example `https://github.com/laradock/laradock/blob/master/nginx/sites/app.conf.example` See your root? I would make 1 config file work and then adjust the rest. The fact that your root ends in `apps`, but then has a couple of subdirectories is interesting. I would then let it end in `app_1/public`. `server_name` is `my_domain.com`? Wouldn't that be a subdomain then? `location` ends in `app_1`? Your nginx is the proxy?

Comment: @웃웃웃웃웃 Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75344177/21107840) it might help.